# IE 11 win 10 text box disabled

Tags: internet-explorer

I am facing compatibility issue in windows 10 Internet explorer . I am using IE 11(11.900) to be precise. The same browser also runs on windows server 2008. One of the IE plugins which works perfectly in windows server 2008 having frequent crash in IE win 10 mode .

IE 11 on win 10:
[image]

The plugin (add on ) works perfectly in windows server 2008 or windows 7 .

Two browser settings are running in compatibility mode . is there any way to run IE as windows server 2008 mode?

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE when the plugin crashes? Could you please provide [a minimal sample to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue? So that we can have a better understanding of the issue and can have a test to see how to help. With only the above description, we can't locate the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou its Oracle hyperion web interactive plugin which supports IE 11 running on windows 7 or windows server 2008. On windows 10 when it tries to open a popup its focus getting distorted and test field becomes non editable . I believe this is a bug in win 10 .

Comment: You could try to compare if there's any difference between the IEs' settings. It seems hard to create a minimal sample and needs a complex trouble-shooting. You could open an assisted support or a virtual agent support in [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/support/). Create a support request may be more efficient in solving your issue.